# how to configure windows ce as router

Tags: routes, windows-ce, router

I'm working on a machine with a panel-pc as interface. This panel has two nics: one (public) connected to the internet, the other (private) connected to a machine internal network.
The internal network has a static configuration.
The panel works with WINCE 6.0.

Now there is a camera that needs to access the internet. For that i thought of enabling the router functionality with the panel acting as a nameserver proxy.

I've tried almost everything but it wont work!

Any suggestions??

Relevant enabled catalog items:
ICS, TCP/IP, wired local area network, IABASE

My registry settings for generating the NK.BIN are:

```
; router settings for camera:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\PCI\RTL81392\Parms\Tcpip]
"IPEnableRouter"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\Tcpip\Parms]
"IPEnableRouter"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"IPEnableRouter"=dword:1

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMM\ConnectionSharing]
"EnablePacketFiltering"=dword:0
"PublicInterface"=multi_sz:"RTL81391"
"PrivateInterface"=multi_sz:"RTL81392"
"EnableDnsProxy"=dword:1
"EnableDhcpAllocator"=dword:1
"DHCPLeaseTime"=dword:5a0
"DhcpAllocationStartRange"=dword:2
"DhcpAllocationEndRange"=dword:5
```

thanks!

Comment: I found the error: I did have to use "PCI\\RTL81391" instead of only the name (as stated in the only documentation :( )